# TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeRevueESR' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

My need is that I want the input "Date de signature de l’offre" to be marked "required" if the option "E - Signature du contrat" is selected.

I do not know what the problem is, it seems to me that everything is okay. But it shows me the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeRevueESR' of undefined
>       at Scope.SupportDemandeCtrl.$scope.matchSelectedTypeRevueESR (SupportDemandeApp.js:70)

Here is the code on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y216fRSgABRKAA04XSoS)

SupportDemandeApp.js :

```
///<reference path="../Scripts/angular.min.js" />
///<reference path="../Scripts/angular-route.min.js" />

var supportDemandeApp = angular.module('supportDemandeApp', ['ngMessages']);

supportDemandeApp.controller('SupportDemandeCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', SupportDemandeCtrl]);

supportDemandeApp.run(function ($rootScope) {
$rootScope.typeOf = function (value) {
    return typeof value;
};
})

supportDemandeApp.directive('stringToNumber', function () {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function (value) {
            return '' + value;
        });
        ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
            return parseFloat(value);
        });
    }
};
});

function SupportDemandeCtrl($scope, $filter) {

//Fonction : Type de contrat (IS/OS)
$scope.typeContrat = function () {
    $scope.typesContrat = ['Niv.I - Impartition IMS',
                            'Niv.II - Impartition TMA / AMS',
                            'Niv.III - Projet',
                            'Niv.IV - Impartition BPO',
                            'Multi - Tiers avec Impartition',
                            'Multi-Tiers CS & Projet',
                            'Vente de licence ou produit sans services ni modification'
                            ];

    $scope.selectedTypeContrat = {};
};

$scope.matchSelectedTypeContrat = function () {
    if (($scope.selectedTypeContrat.typeContrat === 'Niv.I - Impartition IMS') ||
        ($scope.selectedTypeContrat.typeContrat === 'Niv.II - Impartition TMA / AMS') ||
        ($scope.selectedTypeContrat.typeContrat === 'Niv.IV - Impartition BPO') ||
        ($scope.selectedTypeContrat.typeContrat === 'Multi-Tiers avec Impartition'))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
};

//Fonction : Date de signature de l’offre / Type Revue ESR
$scope.typeRevueESR = function () {
    $scope.typesRevueESR = ["A - Faire une offre ou non",
                            "B - Stratégie de l'offre",
                            "A/B",
                            "C - Soumission de l'offre",
                            "A/B/C",
                            "E - Signature du contrat"
                            ];

    $scope.selectedTypeRevueESR = {};
};

$scope.matchSelectedTypeRevueESR = function () {
    if ($scope.selectedTypeRevueESR.typeRevueESR === 'E - Signature du contrat')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
};
}
```

SupportDemande.cshtml :

```
<script src="~/ScriptsJS/SupportDemande.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/ScriptsJS/SupportDemandeApp.js"></script>

<div ng-app="supportDemandeApp" ng-controller="SupportDemandeCtrl">
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="supportDemandeForm" name="supportDemandeForm" method="post" ng-submit="validationSupportDemande(supportDemandeForm.$valid)" novalidate>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="selectTypeRevue" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Type de revue à réaliser<span style="color:red"> *</span></label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <select class="form-control" id="selectTypeRevue" name="selectTypeRevue" ng-model="selectedTypeRevue" required>
                        <option disabled hidden selected></option>
                        <option ng-option>ESR</option>
                        <option ng-option>SSR</option>
                    </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" ng-if="selectedTypeRevue == 'ESR'">
                <label for="selectTypeRevueESR" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Type de revue ESR à réaliser<span style="color:red"> *</span></label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <select class="form-control" id="selectTypeRevueESR" name="selectTypeRevueESR" ng-model="selectedTypeRevueESR.typeRevueESR" ng-init="typeRevueESR()" ng-options="typeRevueESR for typeRevueESR in typesRevueESR" required></select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group has-warning" ng-required="matchSelectedTypeRevueESR()">
                <label for="inputDateSignatureOffre" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Date de signature de l’offre</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputDateSignatureOffre" name="inputDateSignatureOffre" ng-model="inputDateSignatureOffre">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's telling you exactly what the issue is. You haven't defined `selectedTypeRevueESR` therefore you can't set the property `typeRevueESR` on it.

I'm not sure what your exact application logic is here, but you may need to initialize these objects first like this:

```
 $scope.selectedTypeRevueESR = {
     typeRevueESR: ""
 };
```

Comment: It's not working. I've edited my question, and added my need and SupportDemande.cshtml

Comment: @DjSadwell, where are you defining this in your controller?

Comment: $scope.selectedTypeRevueESR = {};

Comment: You need to define it as I provided in my answer outside of a function at the top of your controller.

Comment: @DjSadwell, this does work. See my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pxmU8yY3i7dD5Jd3qbhl?p=preview)

Comment: IT DOES WORK ! THANKS A LOT MAN <3

Comment: @DjSadwell, anytime!